# Spring Batch compatibility: spring-batch 2.2.7 with spring-core 2.5.6

Tags: spring-batch

We recently started to implement batch process in our application using spring batch. The spring-core that we are currently using is 2.5.6. However, the spring-batch 2.2.7 uses spring-core 3.2.9. 
I tried to exclude the spring-core, spring-beans from spring-batch dependency, but still I am facing the following exception. I wanted to know does spring-batch 2.2.7 works with spring-core 2.5.6 ?

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/serializer/Serializer
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.determi
neCandidateConstructors(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:191)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineCon
structorsFromBeanPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:859)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanIn
stance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:831)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getSingleton
FactoryBeanForTypeCheck(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:682)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFa
ctoryBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:614)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isTypeMatch(AbstractBeanFac
tory.java:450)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(
DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:223)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beanNamesForTypeIncludingAncestors(Bea
nFactoryUtils.java:187)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidat
es(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:652)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(De
faultListableBeanFactory.java:610)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$Autowir
edFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:412)
        ... 18 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.core.serializer.Serializer
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could not find explicitly the mention of support for Spring 2.5, but the reference guide has a mention of Spring 2.5 so I think it supports it.

> "The main difference is that the map keys in the example above do not
>   need to be quoted with Spring 2.5, but the quotes are mandatory in
>   Spring 3.0."